# do 2 things at the same time with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a nodejs application with socket.IO, for some home automation. In app.js I receive calls from the interface which works fine, I send those calls to another file/raspberry pi. this also works fine, for basic things like: turn on/off, change color etc. I created this `fade()` function which fades between the led colors, when I call this function(which keep looping as it should) it only loops, and stops receiving other socket calls.

i just need a method to run the `fade()` function at the same time, or another(better?) approach.

underneath my code:

```
let Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;
let socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');
let delay = require('delay');
let ledRed = new Gpio(27, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
let ledGreen = new Gpio(17, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
let ledBlue = new Gpio(22, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});

let fadeState = false;

socket.on('fadeClient',function(data){
    if (fadeState === false){
        fadeState = data;
       // fade()
    }
    console.log("fade " + data);
    fadeState = data;
    console.log("data");
});

function setRGBVal(red, blue, green){
    // console.log('red: '  +red);
    // console.log('blue: ' +blue);
    // console.log('green: ' +green);

    ledRed.pwmWrite(0);
    ledGreen.pwmWrite(0);
    ledBlue.pwmWrite(0);
    ledRed.pwmWrite(Math.round(red));
    ledGreen.pwmWrite(Math.round(blue));
    ledBlue.pwmWrite(Math.round(green));
}

function fade(){
    console.log("inFade");
    while(fadeState === true) {
        console.log(fadeState)
        for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            setRGBVal(i, 0, 0);
            delay(500);
            if (fadeState === true){
                break;
                console.log("piemel");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            setRGBVal(0, i, 0);
            delay(500);
            if (fadeState === true){
                break;
                console.log("piemel");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            setRGBVal(0, 0, i);
            delay(500);
            if (fadeState === true){
                break;
                console.log("piemel");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is single-threaded so a delay() will block the whole application, as you discovered. Use setTimeout() instead, just like in frontend web applications. Something like this:

```
fadeNext(0);

function fadeNext(i) {
  setRGBVal(i, 0, 0);
  if (i < 255) {
    setTimeout(function() { fadeNext(i+1); }, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is the issue, when I remove the delay, it still doesn't work. will try your approach though